# Searching a list of objects for a non empty property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm searching a list of objects for a certain property. I'm repeating this code for a lot of properties, so I'm trying to make the reading of the property as compact as possible.

Here's what I currently have:

```
value = ReadValue(p => p.ProductCatalogId != 0, p => p.ProductCatalogId);

public T ReadValue<T>(Func<MyType, bool> predicate, Func<MyType, T> selector)
{
    return m_settingsPages.Where(predicate).Select(selector).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I always compare against the default value for the type, and always for inequality. I would like to remove the predicate argument. Can I use partial application or a similar technique to get rid of the predicate argument?

Pseudo code:

```
value = ReadFirstValue(p => p.ProductCatalogId);

public T ReadFirstValue<T>(Func<MyType, T> selector) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var predicate = selectorToPredicate(selector); //Compare with default(T) for non equality
    return m_settingsPages.Where(predicate).Select(selector).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

How would selectorToPredicate look and how would I call it?

Comment: In your comments you indicate that you want to compare with default(T), why dont you do that? ie `predicate = p => selector(p).equals(default(T))`

Comment: I didn't know I could. I have much left to learn. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could do something as simple as:

```
Func<MyType, bool> SelectorToPredicate<T>(Func<MyType, T> selector)
{
    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return x => !comparer.Equals(selector(x), default(T));
}
```

One thing to note - if your property is a string property, this *will* return empty strings. Is that what you want?

Comment: It seems that it is not as he checks int value for 0 not NULL, though

Comment: Actually, I might have to avoid empty strings. Can I do that with a specialized function? I'm on .NET 4.

Comment: @vittore: I'm assuming that `ProductCatalogId` is an `int` property, and `default(int)` is 0.

Comment: @CarlR: I would do that with a separate method (`ReadStringValue`).

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, well, yes then.

Comment: There can't be yet another SelectorToPredicate specialized to strings? Like Template Specialization in C++.

Comment: @CarlR: There *could* be... but given that it's *doing something different* I think it would be better not to overload it.

Comment: This class is for reading settings assignable from users in a web application. I think we'll treat empty or whitespace as not assigned throughout the settings.

Comment: @CarlR: Well you *could* check for `T` being `string` within `ReadFirstValue`. It just seems like a nasty use of generics, that's all.

Comment: I was hoping for a `SelectorToPredicate<T>(Func<MyType, T> selector) where T : string` could overload your example. I agree that a checking T for string within ReadFirstValue would look ugly.

Comment: @CarlR: You could overload `ReadFirstValue` with a non-generic overload taking `Func<MyType, string>` - you wouldn't need to call `SelectorToPredicate` then. It would require you to know at *compile*-time (of the caller to `ReadFirstValue`) that you're dealing with a string property though. Pretty fragile.